# How to pass java HashMap in Gatling Feeder

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, hashmap, gatling

I'm attempting to call Map.canBuildFrom(("dataLine", dataLine)); where data line is a HashMap, I want to pass the hashMap , how do I do this ?

```
val myCustomFeeder = new Feeder[String] {
  override def hasNext = true
  override def next: Map[String, String] = {
    var dataLine: java.util.HashMap[String, String] = new RandomDataGenerator().getMessageMap(); // this returns a java.util.HashMap
    Map.canBuildFrom(("dataLine", dataLine)); // does not compile.
  }
}
```

The Error I get is :

```
Error:(91, 11) overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  ()scala.collection.mutable.Builder[(A, B),scala.collection.immutable.Map[A,B]] <and>
  (from: Map.Coll)scala.collection.mutable.Builder[(A, B),scala.collection.immutable.Map[A,B]]
 cannot be applied to ((String, java.util.HashMap[String,String]))
                        Map.canBuildFrom(("dataLine", dataLine));
                            ^
```

Comment: "Does not compile": What is the error you got?

Comment: I updated the error, details

Comment: Why are you doing such thing? If you want to convert java map to scsala map use `scala.collection.JavaConverters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Łukasz suggested, use `JavaConversions`:

```
def next: Map[String, String] = {
  var dataLine: java.util.HashMap[String, String] = ???
  scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap(dataLine).toMap
}
```

Or, using implicits:

```
def next: Map[String, String] = {
  var dataLine: java.util.HashMap[String, String] = ???
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
  dataLine.toMap
}
```

The only drawback here is, as you need to return immutable `Map`, you have to call `toMap` which essentially makes a copy of the whole map.

`mapAsScalaMap` returns a wrapper around Java map, which is cheap operation comparing to copy, so you'd have better performance if you could do that:

```
def next: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String] = {
  var dataLine: java.util.HashMap[String, String] = ???
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
  dataLine
}
```

Comment: @Łukasz:  this does not compile yet , I tried modifying the code to look like this as indicated : ` override def next: Map[String,String] =
     { var dataLine:java.util.HashMap[String, String]= new RandomDataGenerator().getMessageMap(); scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsSca laMap(dataLine).toMap Map.canBuildFrom("dataLine",dataLine)}`

Comment: the `Map.canBuildFrom("dataLine",dataLine)` complains on the same compilation error

Comment: @ChanduD, you don't need to call `Map.canBuildFrom`. Just remove that line. `scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap(dataLine).toMap` gives you the result.

Comment: @ChanduD, I'm not Lukasz, but you're welcome anyway.